# Как отправить http(s) запрос на сервер из программы, чтобы его никто не мог подделать?

Tags: c++, http, безопасность, сеть, защита

Как отправить http(s) запрос на сервер из программы, чтобы его никто не мог подделать?

Программа отправляет некоторую информацию на сервер (статистику), хочу убедиться, что это действительно отправляет моя программа а не злоумышленник

Answer (score 5):

Это вопрос из разряда "Как защитить программу, чтобы её нельзя было сломать?" Ответ простой: **никак**.

Всё, что вы можете — это усложнить работу хакера:

- традиционная защита бинарников (если код нативный, а для C++ это так, то это важный элемент; если компиляция JIT, то защита бесполезна — только от школьников спасёт);
- хитро запрятанные цифровые подписи для запросов (как минимум, не кладите ключ в открытом виде);
- продвинутая валидация на стороне сервера (насколько полученные значения правдоподобные, можно отправлять историю операций и т.п.);
- регулярные обновления клиента и сервера (никому не в радость ломать программу каждый раз);
- слежение за отладкой (запущен ли процесс под отладчиком, присутствуют ли подозрительные процессы);
- и так далее.

Цель — сделать взлом *невыгодным*. Однако если за вашу программу возьмётся кто-то принципиальный (или идейный, или за весьма хорошие деньги), то он сломает что угодно.

Чтобы отвадить от вашей программы кулхацкеров, хватит защиты бинарников и цифровой подписи у запросов. А дальше уже смотрите, насколько вам выгодно защищаться.

Comment: То есть единственный выход - security through obscurity, и даже это поможет только от дурака?

Comment: @zenden2k Запас прочности у obscurity при должном подходе достаточный, чтобы остановить большинство желающих. Ваш софт не будут ломать, если спроса на него практически нет, а на взлом нужны недели плотной работы. То есть профи ваш софт взломать сможет, но не будет этого делать, если его хорошенько не мотивировать.

Answer (score 1):

Если вообще никто, то теоретически никак, но для затруднения этого процесса можно использовать криптографию и средства для запутывания исходного кода.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) можно передавать http(s) запросы.

Защитить передачу данных от подделок можно [электронной цифровой подписью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). Широкий набор криптографических инструментов, в том числе и ЭЦП предоставляет, например, [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Если это нужно сделать для защиты кода - взять пример ка это сделано в скайпе  :), от факта передачи никак

Comment: не для защиты кода. Программа отправляет некоторую информацию на сервер (статистику), хочу убедиться, что это действительно отправляет моя программа а не злоумышленник

Comment: ну тогда надо смотреть как это сделано в банковских программах, торговых площадках. с выдачей эектронных ключей и пр. Как вариант (простейшая защита) привязка к ip , если у клиента не динамически ip